# Nil object when didn't expect it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Legacy Ruby on Rails 2.3 project here. Getting the following error:

```
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of ActiveRecord::Base.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]
```

Extracted source (around line #122):

```
119: <%= link_to 'Printable', { :action => 'print', :id => @incident.id }, { :target => '_blank', :class => "button" } %>
120: <% if isviewable?(@incident) %>
121: 
122:   <%= link_to "Pictures (#{@incident.pictures.count})", incident_pictures_path(@incident), :class => "button" %>
123:   <%= link_to "Suspects (#{@incident.suspects.count})", incident_suspects_path(@incident), :class => "button" %>
124:   <%= link_to "Notes (#{@incident.notes.count})", incident_notes_path(@incident), :class => "button"%>
125:   <%= link_to "Cars (#{@incident.cars.count})", incident_cars_path(@incident), :class => "button" %>
```

Any ideas anyone? Thanks.

Edit: Removing line 122 fixes the exception, but I might need to show a picture if that record has one, so I can't just take out that functionality.

Edit 2: There is also this line in the exception page under Application Trace:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/paperclip-2.3.0/lib/paperclip.rb:303:in `validates_attachment_content_type'
```

Could it be an error with my paperclip plugin?

Comment: Have you inspected the `@incident` object? Are the properties/relation you want to count available?

Comment: There is a has_many :pictures line in the incident model class, but with this particular incident there are no pictures.

Answer (score 0):

```
119: <%= link_to 'Printable', { :action => 'print', :id => @incident.id }, { :target => '_blank', :class => "button" } %>
    <% if @incident.present?%>       #### you need to check for null object. ######
120: <% if isviewable?(@incident) %>
121:
122:   <%= link_to "Pictures (#{@incident.pictures.count})", incident_pictures_path(@incident), :class => "button" %>
123:   <%= link_to "Suspects (#{@incident.suspects.count})", incident_suspects_path(@incident), :class => "button" %>
124:   <%= link_to "Notes (#{@incident.notes.count})", incident_notes_path(@incident), :class => "button"%>
125:   <%= link_to "Cars (#{@incident.cars.count})", incident_cars_path(@incident), :class => "button" %>
```

You need to check for null object, then it will work fine hopefully.

Answer (score 0):

Try using .find_by_id instead of .find in your controller. You then can check the result (@incident.nil?) before going further.

Edit:

How about `@incident.pictures?` to check if there are any?

Comment: The incident object is there, there just aren't any pictures. Removing just the pictures line (line 122) makes the page display just fine.